# Angular: sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml does not render attribute (click)

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I try to render a button and it works fine, but when I click the button it doesn't execute alertWindow function, help!:

app.component.ts:

```
import { 
  Component, 
  ElementRef, 
  OnInit,  
  ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom,
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

 public content: SafeHtml;

 constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

 async ngOnInit() { this.renderButton(); }

 alertWindow() { alert("don't work"); }

 renderButton() {
   
 this.content = 
 this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`
  <button (click)='connectWallet()' class="button">
   Connect your wallet
  </button>`);      
 }
```

app.component.ts;

```
<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
```

Comment: Your (click) is connected to a function connectWallet(), not to alertWindow()

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

> Based on what I understand you wanted to display HTML dynamically at runtime? then solution is to use
> [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver)
> and [ViewContainerRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef)

It will be better if you can provide more details, what you are trying to achieve, so that people can guide you

#### Why it didn't work?

It doesn't work because it is outside of angular, when you use `innerHTML` then whatever you passed to it is pure vanilla HTML and JavaScript

Try this example

```js
(window as any).alertWindow = function () {
  alert("don't works");
};

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
  ...

  renderButton() {
    this.content = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`
    <button onclick='alertWindow()' class="button">Connect your wallet</button>
  `);
  }
}
```

It works right?

As you can see I have moved `alrertWindow` function outside of component's class and added to window variable and also changed `(click)` to `onclick`